# The control DataSource(or DataSourceID) is not set

Tags: c#, autocomplete, telerik, datasource, token

I want to have two `InputType="Token"` textBox. So I found the [`telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox`](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox/examples/populatingwithdata/defaultcs.aspx) That has the property to create tokens.

[image: TokenStyle]

I tried to use the following code in my **aspx** page:

```
<div class="divClass">
    <label for="RadAutoCompleteBox1">
        Continents:</label>
    <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox ID="RadAutoCompleteBox1" runat="server" Width="250" DropDownHeight="150"
        DropDownWidth="250">
    </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
</div>
```

---

And he is my **code behind** page: *(note: this piece of code is **OUT** of `if (!IsPostBack)` but inside the PageLoad())*

```
RadAutoCompleteBox1.DataSource = new List<string>() { "Europe", "America", "Asia", "Africa", "Australia" };
```

I use in the same pages others examples with telerik, like `telerik:RadComboBox`, `telerik:RadWindow`, `telerik:RadTabStrip` and others ... Everyone works fine!

---

When I load the page and try to add any entry to `RadAutoCompleteBox1` I got the following error:

[image: Error]

---

What am I doing wrong? what am I missing?

- I tried to add `RadAutoCompleteBox1.DataBind();`
- I tried an empty ArrayList `RadAutoCompleteBox1.DataSource = new ArrayList();`

PS: As I said, I need two of those ***"Token TextBox kind"***, the second can't have an DataSource because I'll be using `AllowCustomEntry="true"`. This is why I tried with an empty ArrayList

---

I'm not sure if this is the best approach to my problem. But, the mechanic is exact what I need, I just can't make this work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure if this is how it should be done, but it works.

I used the `[WebMethod]`

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> LoadRadAutoCompleteBox1()
{
    return new List<string>() { "Europe", "America", "Asia", "Africa", "Australia" };
}

[WebMethod]
public static List<string> LoadRadAutoCompleteBox2()
{
    return new List<string>();
}
```

And in the aspx

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox runat="server" ID="RadAutoCompleteBox1" EmptyMessage="Please type here" SelectMethod="LoadRadAutoCompleteBox1" 
    InputType="Token" Width="350">
</telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>

<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox runat="server" ID="RadAutoCompleteBox2" EmptyMessage="Please type here" SelectMethod="LoadRadAutoCompleteBox2" 
    AllowCustomEntry="true" InputType="Token" Width="350">
</telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and works for me. Here is my code:

```
<div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Token mode</legend>
                <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox runat="server" ID="RadAutoCompleteBox1" EmptyMessage="Please type here"
                    AllowCustomEntry="true" InputType="Token" Width="350">
                </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Token mode</legend>
                <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox runat="server" ID="RadAutoCompleteBox2" EmptyMessage="Please type here"
                    AllowCustomEntry="true" InputType="Token" Width="350">
                </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

And here is my code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadAutoCompleteBox1.DataSource = new List<string>() { "Europe", "America", "Asia", "Africa", "Australia" };
        RadAutoCompleteBox2.DataSource = new List<string>();
    }
```

And here is my output

[image]

The AutoComplete demos are found here:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx

Let me know if this helped you

Comment: Thanks for your reply, gonna test it here and let you know.

Comment: Try calling DataBind() after setting the datasource